# C#: Can I extend a foreign class such that it implements a local interface

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I have 2 assemblies( foreign and local ). The foreign assembly cannot be modified. I would like to extend a foreign class such that it will now implement a local interface. Is this possible in C#?

EDIT:
I know that I can do the following:

```
// foreign.dll
namespace DX {
    public struct Vector3 {
        ...
    }
}

// local.dll
namespace MyDX {
    public static class Extensions {
        public static void MyExtensionMethod( this Vector3 vec, int index ){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm interested in doing is forcing the foreign class/struct to implement a particular interface (without using inheritance ). I would like to use Vector3 as a type in a generic class:

```
public class MyGeneric<T> where T: IComparable<T> {
    T _value;
}
```

The above struct: Vector3 does not implement IComparable but I would like to use reflection to implement the interface so that I can use the foreign class/struct in its existing form (ie. w/o using inheritance). Inheritance may be necessary...

Comment: That cannot be done. Can you describe what you want to achieve through this? Cause it sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: `class Local : Foreign, ILocalInterface`? If you need to use the interface only it should be indifferent which class implements it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve from doing this?

Comment: With your edit you are asking a completely different question. Your question was about subclassing of classes; now apparently it is about interface implementation on structs.

Comment: The short answer to your new question is: nope, you can't do that in C#. The restriction that T be comparable is a bad design precisely because of the issue you have discovered; the better design would be to have the method in question take a comparison object or delegate.

Answer (score 9):

> Can I extend a foreign class such that it implements a local interface

Sure, provided that the foreign class is not sealed. (And, of course, accessible to the local project, and so on.)

```
// Foreign.DLL
namespace F 
{ 
  public class B 
  {
    public void Foo() { }
  }
}

// Local.DLL
interface IFooBar 
{ 
  void Foo();
  void Bar();
}
class D : F.B, IFooBar
{
  public void Bar() { }
}
```

There, `D` has extended `F.B`, as required, and `D` implements `IFooBar`, as required. Notice how `F.B.Foo` meets the contractual obligation of `IFooBar` even though it is on the base class.

If the foreign class is sealed then you'll have to use composition rather than inheritance.

However, I agree with the commenter that says that this smells like an XY problem. Can you say what problem you are *really* trying to solve, in more detail? Because there might be a better way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the narrow sense (like *extension methods*), *extension interfaces* are currently not supported by the C# language. But in a wider sense, you can use inheritance or composition as explained in @Eric's answer.

Supporting extension interfaces in C# has been briefly discussed in 2015 in [Roslyn issue 3357](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3357). However, this can't be fully implemented by the C# compiler alone, as it requires CLR support to ensure reference equality between `(ITheAddedInterface)x` and `x`. The topic seems to be abandoned for now.

Other CIL languages such as [F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions) have a much more flexible extension mechanism than C#. But C# is catching up, as seen e.g. in [C# language issue no. 164](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164), and the video [A Preview of C# 8](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/A-Preview-of-C-8-with-Mads-Torgersen#time=32m11s).